# I want to fetch lazy my user entity but it not work

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, relationship

I have my Entity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdBy", "createdDate", "lastModifiedBy", "lastModifiedDate" }, allowGetters = true)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public abstract T getId();

    @NotNull
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 13, updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @NotNull
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 13)
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
    //GETTER AND SETTER
}
```

second class

```
package cnas.gov.md.domain;

import cnas.gov.md.domain.enumeration.DecisionStatus;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * A Decision.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "decision")
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class Decision extends AbstractAuditingEntity<UUID> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "decision_nr")
    private String decisionNr;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private DecisionStatus status;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Application application;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "order_nr", nullable = false)
    private Integer orderNr;

    @Column(name = "examined_date")
    private Instant examinedDate;

    @Column(name = "examined_by")
    private String examinedBy;

    @Column(name = "verified_date")
    private Instant verifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "verified_by")
    private String verifiedBy;


    @Column(name = "approved_date")
    private Instant approvedDate;

    @Column(name = "approved_by")
    private String approvedBy;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", referencedColumnName = "login", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User createdUser;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by", referencedColumnName = "login", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User lastModifiedUser;
}
```

I want to fetch lazy  createdUser and lastModifiedUser if is possible, and use eager fetch when i want with entity graph, I try to use fetch = LAZY but it dont work. I need this for get some info about user and Yes i can't use in my AbstractAuditingEntity reference to user because that class extend more where i don't need info about user.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the OneToOne relation. According to [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-lazy-loading-one-to-one/)
Configuring lazy loading for one-to-one associations is not as easy as it is for other associations.

With some Hibernate versions, you can set the optional attribute of the @OneToOne annotation to false to avoid the eager fetching. Hibernate then always initializes the manuscript attribute with a proxy object. Unfortunately, this doesn’t work for all Hibernate version. If it works with your Hibernate version, you need to be prepared that it might change with future updates. I mean something like this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by", referencedColumnName = "login", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User lastModifiedUser;
```